# Create method in Angular 4 with http call and handle response

Tags: angular, es6-promise

I have a provider class having a request function. It works fine:

```
sendRequest(requestBody:any,URL:string){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body=requestBody;
    body.key=this.key;

    this.http.post(this.url+URL, body, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        let json=JSON.parse(data['_body']);

          let toast=this.toast.create({
            message:json.response,
            duration:3000,
            position:'top'
          });
          toast.present();
          return json;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
  }
```

I want to call this method and want json response in another class. I tried calling in promise but didn't worked out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I want to perform toast as well as I tried returning this.http.post... it is returning a subscribe object. How can I fetch json data from that?

**Edit # 2 **
I successfully returned the data using map on definition and subscribe on call side.

```
return this.http.post(this.url+URL, body, options)
      .map((data) => {
        let json=JSON.parse(data['_body']);

          let toast=this.toast.create({
            message:json.response,
            duration:3000,
            position:'top'
          });
          toast.present();
          return json;
      }
```

and called using

```
this.request.sendRequest(requestBody,'api/login').subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Toast works too.

**Solved**

Comment: you have to return it: `return this.http.post ...` then you can call it from another method

Comment: Check this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040889/javascript-angular-httpclient-get-data-from-url-and-pass-outside-method/50040949#50040949)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 handling http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941836/angular2-handling-http-response)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to append headers and display a toatser, consider using an [**interceptor**](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) from the new [**Http Client module**](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) :

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  const clone = req.clone({ setHeaders: headers });

  return next
    .handle(clone || req)
    .map(response => {
      this.toast.create(...);
      return response;
    });
}
```